# 500 Internal Server Error on all my sub-domain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, cpanel, internal-server-error

Am having error on sub-domain and I guess it is due to my .htaccess file. I cannot access my sub-domain at all. The main domain is working fine. just only the sub-domains are having the 500 internal error.

> Internal Server Error,
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@admin.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

how do i fix? Thanks

Comment: Check your error log file.

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the `.htaccess` and `index.php` solutions for the same problem. Turns out it was simply a wildcard problem. I had the wildcard set to:

```
/public_html/MYDOMAIN.com
```

It needs to be set to:

```
/public_html
```

This fixed my problem.
Hope it helps someone with the same frustration!